# yaws appmods Accept-Language A record is not correct

Tags: erlang, yaws

I work with yaws from a docker container for years, basically taken from https://github.com/segeda/docker-yaws/blob/master/Dockerfile:

```
FROM erlang:20-alpine
...
&& git clone https://github.com/klacke/yaws.git /yaws-src \
...
```

Things just used to run fine, but all of a sudden my code fails, and I cannot find the error(s). I could not even find a git version which worked when it had before, so I suspect it might not be a code fault, but then -- what could it be?

It cannot be my code, can it? Because I boiled it down to the example given in http://yaws.hyber.org/appmods.yaws and produced the same error:

```
%% this is my appmod called from yaws

-module(myurl).
-author('kklepper').
-include("../../include/yaws_api.hrl").
%-include("/usr/local/lib/yaws/include/yaws_api.hrl"). 
% relative or absolute -- either way same result
-export([out/1]).

-define(debug, true).
-ifdef(debug).
-define(trace(Str, X), io:format("Mod:~w line:~w ~p ~p~n", 
                                 [?MODULE,?LINE, Str, X])).
-else.
-define(trace(X, Y), true).
-endif.

box(Str) ->
    {'div',[{class,"box"}],
     {pre,[],Str}}.

out(A) ->
?trace('A', A),
    {ehtml,
     [{p,[],
       box(io_lib:format("A#arg.appmoddata = ~p~n"
                         "A#arg.appmod_prepath = ~p~n"
                         "A#arg.querydata = ~p~n",
                         [A#arg.appmoddata,
                          A#arg.appmod_prepath,
                          A#arg.querydata]))}]}.
```

The file `yaws_api.hrl` was and still is present:

```
/yaws # ls -la /usr/local/lib/yaws/include/yaws_api.hrl
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     50            5563 May 13  2018 /usr/local/lib/yaws/include/yaws_api.hrl
```

With `trace` you can see that the A record is not correct -- no `A#arg.querydata` etc. -- hence the error. Why?

Obviously, `querydata`, for example, as such is given: `lg=en`.

```
Mod:myurl line:22 'A' {arg,#Port<0.2934>,
                          {{10,255,0,2},52801},
                          {headers,"keep-alive",
                              "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, image/webp, image/apng, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
                              "voxx.b2d",undefined,undefined,undefined,
                              undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36",
                              undefined,[],undefined,undefined,undefined,
                              undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                              undefined,
                              [{http_header,11,'Accept-Language',undefined,
                                   "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"},
                               {http_header,10,'Accept-Encoding',undefined,
                                   "gzip, deflate"},
                               {http_header,0,"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
                                   undefined,"1"}]},
                          {http_request,'GET',
                              {abs_path,"/industries?lg=en"},
                              {1,1}},
                          {http_request,'GET',
                              {abs_path,"/industries?lg=en"},
                              {1,1}},
                          undefined,"/industries","lg=en","industries","/ci",
                          "/","/ci/industries",undefined,undefined,<0.163.0>,
                          [],[],[],"/industries",myurl}

=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Oct-2019::00:46:06 ===


ERROR erlang code threw an uncaught exception:
 File: appmod:0
Class: error
Exception: {badrecord,arg}
Req: {http_request,'GET',{abs_path,"/industries?lg=en"},{1,1}}
Stack: [{myurl,out,1,
               [{file,"/usr/local/lib/yaws/voxx/ebin/myurl.erl"},{line,29}]},
        {yaws_server,deliver_dyn_part,8,
                     [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,2921}]},
        {yaws_server,aloop,4,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1274}]},
        {yaws_server,acceptor0,2,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1073}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]
```

By now I ran out of ideas. Any hint?

The data in question seems to be there. I am interested among others in language data and used to get the accepted language from `A` like so:

```
get_lang(A) -> 
    find_lang(find_http_header('Accept-Language', (A#arg.headers)#headers.other)).

find_http_header(Key,Headers) when is_list(Headers) ->
        case lists:keysearch(Key,3,Headers) of
            {value,{_,_,_,_,Value}} -> Value;
            false -> undefined
        end.

find_lang(AcceptLanguage) ->
    case AcceptLanguage of
        undefined ->
            "en";
        _ ->
            L = lists:nth(1,string:tokens(
                lists:nth(1,string:tokens(
                    lists:nth(1,string:tokens(AcceptLanguage, ";"))
                    ,","))
            ,"-")),
            L
    end.
```

Without the correct data structure, this cannot work.

Comment: The current version of Yaws, 2.0.7, and Yaws `master` both pass all its tests on Erlang/OTP versions from 17.0 to 22.1, and the tests include access to `querydata` in the `#arg` record. I suspect your appmod has not been recompiled with the current definition of the `#arg` record.

Comment: @SteveVinoski Well, my version is 2.0.7, and I tested interactively, so recompilation happens automatically.

Comment: I copied your `myrul.erl` code posted in your question, compiled it, specified it in my `yaws.conf` as an appmod, directed a request to it via Yaws 2.0.7, and it worked perfectly. I recommend checking your load path to make sure you're getting the right `myurl` appmod, and I'd also make sure you have just a single installation of Yaws in order to rule out any accidental mixture of old and new versions. If you're still having trouble after that, perhaps try contacting me directly so we can figure out a way to debug further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A detail you included in your question shows that your appmod is getting a `badrecord` exception when trying to access the `#arg` record that Yaws passes to it. There are a couple ways to get such an exception:

1. Pass an instance of a data type other than the expected record type to the function. This isn't happening in this case, since Yaws is calling the function and is correctly passing an `#arg` record instance.
2. Compile the caller and the called function with two different definitions of the same record. We can simulate this problem in an Erlang shell as follows:

   - First, define a record `#arg` containing two fields
   - Define a function that takes an instance of that record as an argument and returns the value of one of the fields
   - Redefine the record in the shell to have just one field
   - Pass an instance of the redefined record to the function, which will cause a `badrecord` exception

```
        1> rd(arg, {f,g}).
        arg
        2> F = fun(A) -> A#arg.f end.
        #Fun<erl_eval.7.126501267>
        3> rd(arg, {f}).
        arg
        4> F(#arg{f=1}).
        ** exception error: {badrecord,arg}
```

Since you're using Yaws 2.0.7 and you're also cloning Yaws from github, it's likely you're  compiling some part of your code, probably your appmod, against the Yaws master branch and then running it against 2.0.7. Sometime after I tagged Yaws 2.0.7 on github, I accepted a [change that added a new field](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/commit/a93198fdfb935a31ad196c225a00e9a52d9cf801) to the `#arg` record definition. What this means is that any `#arg` record Yaws 2.0.7 creates and passes to your appmod will result in a `badrecord` exception since the appmod expects a record containing the additional field.

I can think of a few ways to avoid this problem:

- Get rid of your Yaws github clone and build everything against your installation of Yaws 2.0.7.
- In your Yaws clone, `git checkout yaws-2.0.7` so that anything you access or use from the clone is the same as what's in your Yaws 2.0.7 installation.
- Uninstall Yaws 2.0.7, then compile and install from your Yaws clone. Perhaps apply a local tag first, then build and install from that, so that your deployments can be more easily reproduced, and so that you can grab Yaws updates from github without breaking anything locally.

Comment: I've had a similar issue, and traced it back to a version discrepancy between `yaws` and `yaws_api.hrl`